# lxml object identifiers appear to be reused while objects are alive

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using Python 3.6.8 and lxml-4.3.4 on Ubuntu.

What I'm after is breaking up large XML content into fragment files to make the easier to work, and keep the source filename and line number for parsed elements so I can form useful parse-time error messages. The errors I'll raise are specific to my application when the XML is otherwise well-formed.

Here's some example XML fragment files:

one.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>
  <one>1</one>
  <one>11</one>
  <one>111</one>
  <one>1111</one>
</data>
```

two.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>
  <two>2</two>
  <two>22</two>
  <two>222</two>
  <two>2222</two>
  <two>22222</two>
  <two>222222</two>
</data>
```

My plan is to use lxml to parse each file, and simply stitch the element trees together to have a single  root. Then the rest of my program can consume the full tree.

If the content of an element is invalid to my application, I want to give the fragment file and line number it came from. lxml already has the line number, but not the source file. So I want to track that. Note I decide not to try and extend lxml's classes and go with a map of element object identifier to fragment file, which I expect is durable even if lxml refactors its source.

```
from lxml import etree

# Too much data for one source file, so let's define
# fragment files, each of which looks like a stand
# alone XML file w/ header and root <data>...</data>
# to make syntax highlighters happy.
xmlFragmentFiles = ['one.xml', 'two.xml']

# lxml tracks line number for parsed elements, but not
# source filename. Rather than try to extend the deep
# inner classes of the module, let's try keeping a map
# from parsed elements to fragment file they just came
# from.
element2fragment = {}
def AddFragmentFileToETree(element, fragmentFile):
  # The entry we're just about to add.
  print('%s:%s' % (id(element), fragmentFile))
  element2fragment[id(element)] = fragmentFile
  for child in element:
    AddFragmentFileToETree(child, fragmentFile)

# Fabricate a root that we'll stitch each fragment's
# children onto as we parse them.
root = etree.fromstring('<data></data>')
AddFragmentFileToETree(root, 'Programmatic Root')

for filename in xmlFragmentFiles:
  # It doesn't seem to matter whether we create a new
  # parser per fragment, or reuse a single parser.
  parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True)
  subroot = etree.parse(filename, parser).getroot()  
  for child in subroot:
    root.append(child)
    AddFragmentFileToETree(child, filename)

# Clearly the final desired tree is here, and presumably
# all the subelements we care about are reachable from
# the programmatic root meaning the objects are still
# live, so why did any object identifier get reused?
print(etree.tostring(
  root, encoding=str, pretty_print=True))
```

When I run this I can see that the entire desired tree with each distinct element of the fragment files is all there with a pretty-print. However, looking at the map entries we're inserting, we can clearly see objects are being reused!?

```
140611035114248:Programmatic Root
140611035114056:one.xml <-- see here
140611035114376:one.xml
140611035114440:one.xml
140611035114056:one.xml <-- and here
140611035114312:two.xml
140611035114120:two.xml
140611035114056:two.xml <-- and here
140611035114312:two.xml
140611035114120:two.xml
140611035114056:two.xml <-- and again
<data><one>1</one>
  <one>11</one>
  <one>111</one>
  <one>1111</one>
<two>2</two>
  <two>22</two>   <-- yet all distinct elements still exist
  <two>222</two>
  <two>2222</two>
  <two>22222</two>
  <two>222222</two>
</data>
```

Any suggestions what's up with the objects? Perhaps I should stay away from lxml that is a c library? I switched to lxml just for the line number tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to pursue extending/customizing the parser... and found the answer to this original question.

https://lxml.de/element_classes.html

They warn that the python Element proxies are stateless,

> Element instances are created and garbage collected at need, so there
>   is normally no way to predict when and how often a proxy is created
>   for them.

They go on to say, if you really need them to carry state, you have to keep a live reference *to each one*:

```
proxy_cache = list(root.iter())
```

That worked for me. I assumed the root was enough when elements would have live references to children, but the proxies apparently appear on demand from the real tree maintained in C.